# Checking if two finite lines intersect

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry

I'm having trouble of finding out if two finite lines intersect. I have two finite lines (A,B),(C,D) and I need to check if they intersect. The location isn't necessary because if the two intersect, I will just delete one of the lines. I know this can be done somewhat easily with the Line2D libraries in Java but I want to do this from "scratch".

I want to use this to create a map of points with as many lines as possible connecting different points but I do not want any intersections.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you do this by hand? If not, you should pick up an algebra book and learn how.

Comment: in 2D all (unbounded) lines intersect unless they are parallel. Calculate their intersection point assuming they're unbounded and then check if it's within the bounds.

Comment: note that a "map of points with as many lines as possible" without intersections yields a triangulation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(geometry) the most usful of which is the Delaunay triangulation

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you first learn how to do this by hand. The steps are

1. Find the equations for both lines.
2. Solve a system of two equations with two variables and determine whether or not the lines intersect.
3. If step 2 gives a solution, determine if it lies within the two line segments.

If you do not understand the terminology I use here, I suggest you find a high school algebra text book or google for more information.